# Class not found exception with some builds

Tags: android, kotlin, otto

I translated fragment to Kotlin.
Inside it I have method tagged with Otto's `@Subscriebe` tag to listen for network communication.
When I run some builds this fragment is created and visible, but when data is downloaded and Otto tries to call this tagged method I got `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: (...)/app/ui/fragments/ProfileCoverFragment$fillFromUserProfile$1;
       at (...).ui.fragments.ProfileCoverFragment.fillFromUserProfile(ProfileCoverFragment.kt:136)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.squareup.otto.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:89)
       at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatch(Bus.java:386)
       at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatchQueuedEvents(Bus.java:369)
       at com.squareup.otto.Bus.post(Bus.java:338)
       at (...).communication.DefaultCallback.success(DefaultCallback.java:32)
       at (...).app.communication.CommunicationManager$7.success(CommunicationManager.java:463)
       at (...).app.communication.CommunicationManager$7.success(CommunicationManager.java:459)
       at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

After rebuild issue is temporarily fixed. But it still can be found in some builds.
I'm looking for a way to get stable build process with gradle.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @nhaarman I'm looking for a way to get stable build process.

Comment: In my experience, this only happens when converting java files to kotlin. Since this is a one-time transformation, this shouldn't be a problem when just writing kotlin. Assuming it only happens when converting java to kotlin, that is.

Comment: Possibly - but I still suffer from this bugs and some builds are still affected with this issue. Do you suggest to rewrite this class from scratch "manually", instead of using translated one?

Comment: Won't `./gradlew clean build` help? My guess is that some compilation step fails due to the transformation - it compiled the java version, but now there is a kt version.

Comment: For me `Build -> Clean Project` or `./gradlew clean` fix class not found issues.

Comment: This issue occurs also on release builds with clean dependancy - issue is quite random. It seems that it's more probably to occur after changing code of the ProfileCoverFragment. Anyway - I have no 100% path to both reproduce or avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html):
Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:
The forName method in class Class.
The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.
but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.

The possible reason could be, that gradle hadn't included/updated libraries properly.
To ensure that all libraries are included properly, do the follow steps:

1. Delete `~/.gradle` file
2. In Android Studio go to File -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart`
3. On the appeared popup, press `Invalidate and Restart`
4. After Android Studio restarted and synchronized, rebuild the whole project